# I'm having edittext padding problems

Tags: android, css, xml, android-layout, textview

I'm having issues with the padding of TextView. I want to start writing something from the top not from center of TextView Box. Please see the code and Screenshot.

TextView Code:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:background="@drawable/edittextstyle"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:id="@+id/review_comments"/>
```

edittextstyle.xml

```
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:thickness="0dp"
   android:shape="rectangle">
   <stroke android:width="1dp"
   android:color="#000000"/>

   <corners android:radius="2dp" />


   <gradient
   android:startColor="#C8C8C8"
   android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
   android:type="linear"
   android:angle="270"/>
   </shape>

http://i.imgur.com/p9rZDjW.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to your EditText:

```
android:gravity="top|left"
```